# How to change colour of disabled button in styles.js

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass

I have a button in styles.js

```
export const Button = styled.button`
  background: ${(props) => (props.isSubtract ? `#0F4379` : `#F5F6F9`)};
  border-radius: 30%;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 4px
`;
```

I would like to change the colour when the button is disabled from the regular default grey to yellow. I have seen many methods on how to do it using css but since I have a styles.js file already I don't want to add a css file as well.

Any tips on how to change it in a .js file?

I have tried adding:

```
  &:disabled {
    background: #FFFF00;
  }
```

but that did not help

Comment: Are you using a library? If so, you should edit your post and add it as a tag

Comment: You appear to be using some framework, like React and styled components, plus perhaps SASS or LESS or some kind of preprocessor. It is important to add tags for those frameworks and libraries, otherwise people look at your code and say, "that's not valid JS and CSS!"

Comment: Thanks, have added the tags now

Answer (score 1):

Why not just pass a prop called disabled and do the same as you are doing with the background?

in any case, I believe you are using styled components?

```
:disabled {
  ...  
}
```

should do the trick

Comment: I added  `:disabled { background: #FFFF00; }` but it did not work

Answer (score 0):

```js
  const Button = styled.button`
    &:disabled: ${({ disabled }) => (disabled ? true : false)};
    background-color: ${({ disabled }) => !disabled ? 'blue' : 'gray'};
    cursor: ${({ disabled }) => (!disabled ? 'pointer' : null)}; 
    `
 const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(true)
    <Button disabled={disabled}  onClick={(e) =>submitHandler(e)}>Submit</Button>
```